# Want to trace something when Windows.Window is closed?

Tags: c#

I have a class which inherits from Windows.Window:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
```

I want to LOG something (logger.log("Closing Application")) when it closes (no matter how - except for when process is killed or course).

Is there a way for my to overide or catch an event or something in my class that will allow me to do this without negatively affecting the proper closing of my window?
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can override OnClosed method and add your stuff there:

```
protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e)
{
    logger.log("Closing Application")
    base.OnClosed(e);
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.onclosed.aspx